# Web control is not safe

Tags: 2010, development

I have a code which is deployed with the delegate control, but when i try to call it in the logs i see an error:

> class 'My.Custom.MyWebControl': The control with
>   assembly name xxx' class name
>   'My.Custom.MyWebControl' is not allowed for web at URL
>   'http://.... The type is not registered as
>   safe.

So i did register it as safe, because in the web.config i see the following:

> SafeControl Assembly="xxxx" Namespace="My.Custom" TypeName="*"

My question, if this is registered as safe why do i get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,

1) make sure your ammending the correct web application web.config!

2) make sure the safeControl is correct.... by that i mean make sure the ID is the same (check the error assembly id and assembly name), the assembly is correct and also the namespace is correct

3) you can check on the above within project and assembly folder (c:\windows\assembly) goto the file name dll and check the properties.

update the safecontrol accordingly to the information above, most of the safecontrol data can be taken from the error message!

then do iisrest, just incase dll is not updated within assembly, and forces chacing of any data to be rechecked!